# Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 on CentOS Error endorsing chaincode?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I am running CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core).

Running the "first network" sample of the brand new Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 out yesterday I am getting the error:

> Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error starting container: API error (500): {"message":"oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:339: container init caused \\"read init-p: connection reset by peer\\"\"\n"}

How do I debug further?

My complete installation procedure of prereqs was as follows:

```
sudo yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2 policycoreutils-python git dos2unux unzip gcc-c++ make
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
sudo yum makecache fast
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.9-4.el7.noarch.rpm
yum -y install docker-ce
sudo yum -y install docker-ce
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo docker run hello-world
sudo usermod -aG docker root
sudo usermod -aG docker vagrant
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install -y ./epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install -y python-pip
sudo pip install docker-compose
sudo yum upgrade python*
cd
mkdir docker-compose-hello-world
cd docker-compose-hello-world
echo 'my-test:' > ./docker-compose.yml
echo '  image: hello-world' >> ./docker-compose.yml
docker-compose up
sudo docker-compose up
cd
mkdir golang
cd golang
echo downloading go1.8.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.8.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo cp ./go1.8.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz /usr/local
cd /usr/local
sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.8.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo vi /etc/profile
cd
sudo curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo bash -
sudo yum install -y nodejs
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
cd
git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.git
sudo docker run hello-world
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo docker run hello-world
cd fabric-samples
# Stackoverflow validation asked me to replace short URL
# goo.gl/iX9dek with long one below:
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap-1.0.0.sh | sudo bash
cd first-network
yes | sudo ./byfn.sh -m generate
yes | sudo ./byfn.sh -m up
```

My NodeJs (node) version is v6.11.1

My npm version is 5.2.0

My Golang version is go1.8.3 linux/amd64

Thanks in advance for any enlightenment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!

Inspired by reference https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34046, I upgraded the Linux kernel using the instructions at:

https://www.tecmint.com/install-upgrade-kernel-version-in-centos-7/

Works perfectly after a reboot and a selection of the new kernel in the boot menu.

Downside: the Vagrant shared folders between the Windows 7 host OS and the CentOS virtual machine no longer work, but that should be fixed by the next Oracle Virtualbox client tools update.

Comment: Updating CentOS 7.2 to 7.3 also resolves this issue and is the recommended approach.